# TinyMCE Editor :5.2.2

Tags: javascript, asp.net, model-view-controller, tinymce

I want to have a (table) toolbar in the tinymce
the default one not contain it , this is my code

```
 <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b99e675b6e.js"></script>


    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>TintMCE App</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {

            tinymce.init({
                selector: 'textarea',
                toolbar: "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | table | fontsizeselect",

                width: 1000,
                height: "200",
                setup: function (ed) {
                    ed.on('keyup', function (e) {
                        var count = CountCharacters();
                        document.getElementById("character_count").innerHTML = "Characters: " + count;
                    });
                }
            });
        }
```

how i can add table ? try to use plugin like this

```
tinymce.init({
  plugins: "table",
  menubar: "table",
  toolbar: "table tabledelete | tableprops tablerowprops tablecellprops | tableinsertrowbefore tableinsertrowafter tabledeleterow | tableinsertcolbefore tableinsertcolafter tabledeletecol
"
});
```

but not work , any help

Answer (score 0):

Add the plugins option to your tinymce.init and include the table plugin. For example:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  plugins: "table",
  toolbar: "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | table | fontsizeselect",
  width: 1000,
  height: "200"
  // ...
});
```

Comment: thank you , but the table borders are breaking as dashed lines. Can u help me to figure this out ?